# When Rain Lilies Bloom

Tags: botany

I have had the Pink Rain Lilies in a large pot for over 10 years. In that time span, I have noticed it doesn't matter how much water, or what kind, is given to them, I water them daily in warm weather. They do not ever bloom unless there is a storm. For instance, I am in subtropical Queensland, Australia and a few nights ago, we had an electrical storm. It started 4 nearby fires. I heard a couple of drops of rain on the roof, but it stopped as fast as it started. Where my pot of lilies is sitting, I doubt a rain drop even fell on them. I have experienced these kinds of dry storms many times in the past, it's very typical here. The next morning, there was a Pink Rain Lily flower, as is the case after every storm, rain or dry. So, my question is, could it be the nitrogen released in a storm that they are sensitive to?